# get annotation errors when using bigquery

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Im following to this tutorial to get data from bigquery for my symfony project: [cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-php)
. But when I run my function, I get this error:

> The annotation \"@type\" in method
>   Google\Cloud\BigQuery\QueryResults::rows() was never imported. Did
>   you maybe forget to add a \"use\" statement for this annotation?"

In the same case , I write this code to test:

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
            'projectId' => $this->projectId,
        ]);
return $bigQuery;
```

and the result I get is:

> The annotation \"@type\" in method
>   Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient::__construct() was never
>   imported. Did you maybe forget to add a \"use\" statement for this
>   annotation?"

2 functions above are in Google Cloud Libraries so I can not make any changes.
So, how can I fix these errors?

Comment: It looks like Symfony (or perhaps Doctrine -- are you using Doctrine as well?) is attempting to parse the annotations on `BigQueryClient::__construct()`. This will fail. Check your framework configuration to limit the classes which the annotation parser will read.

Comment: @jdp thank you for your help, Im trying to search on gg to fix and waiting for other answers